# Java filter - conditionally change response body based on request

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, servlet-filters

I have a servlet filter that intercepts requests and checks for a custom "encrypted" header:

```
public class EncryptionFilter extends GenericFilterBean{

@Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain) {
    final HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    if (httpRequest.getHeader("EncryptedCommunication") != null){
        decryptedRequest = /*decrypt request body and forward to next filter*/
        encryptedResponse = /*encrypt request body and forward to next filter*/
        filterChain.doFilter(decryptedRequest, encryptedResponse);
    }
    else { /* communication not encrypted */
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
  }
}
```

When the header exist I should decrypt the request body and also encrypt the response body.
Otherwise, should leave the request/response body unchanged.

How can I change the response only when needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a HttpServletResponseWrapper example is :

```
filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest,
        new HttpServletResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse) {
            @Override
            public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
                if (!HTTPCacheHeader.ETAG.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    super.setHeader(name, value);
                }
            }
        });
```

See http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper

This is an example of how the body can be set :

```
public class ReadTwiceHttpServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

private ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

public ReadTwiceHttpServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
    super(request);
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(request.getInputStream(), outputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray())));
}

@Override
public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    final ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
    return new ServletInputStream() {

        @Override
        public int readLine(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            return inputStream.read(b, off, len);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isFinished() {
            return inputStream.available() > 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isReady() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void setReadListener(ReadListener arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return inputStream.read();
        }
    };
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        outputStream.write(body.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getBody() {
    return new String(outputStream.toByteArray());
}
```

See [How to get the XML from POST request and modify it in Servlet Filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38614799/how-to-get-the-xml-from-post-request-and-modify-it-in-servlet-filter/38616378#38616378)

Comment: This does not answer the question since I want to change the response body and not the header.

Comment: Since you have accepted the answer can you update your comment? Thank you.