# Spring boot - How to log 500 response body to console

Tags: java, spring, logging

I've created a filter for spring (using spring boot v1.5) which is triggered on every request using OncePerRequestFilter as follows:

```
@Component
class LogRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogRequestFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrappedResponse = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);

        int responseStatus = wrappedResponse.getStatusCode();

        if (responseStatus == 500) {
            String requestUri = wrappedRequest.getRequestURI();
            byte[] responseBodyBytes = wrappedResponse.getContentAsByteArray();
            logger.error("{}, {}, {}", responseStatus, requestUri, new String(responseBodyBytes));
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, response);
    }
}
```

My problem it that I need to log the response body when an error occurs. However I get no data from getContentAsByteArray() even though the user receives the following response from spring:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1512745726835,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/documents/2017-02-17"
}
```

While debugging I can see that the request URI is correct, but response body is missing. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38614799/how-to-get-the-xml-from-post-request-and-modify-it-in-servlet-filter/38616378#38616378)

Comment: He's using the ContentCachingResponseWrapper which is designed for exactly this case. It's just a bit tricky to use it without documentation.

Comment: @Gorazd I agree, just up voted you, I think you could show the code for the next person.

Comment: I found out that I can access all requests which results 200 OK using the above code. Only 500 response body is not passed to the filter.

Comment: I don't think there is a body

Answer (score 2):

Move your `doFilter` method call before you read the content of `wrappedResponse`.
At the very end call `wrappedResponse.copyBodyToResponse()`.