# Set value from header to request DTO

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, header

I'm using String Boot for my app. In interceptor i can get value from header and would like to add it to request DTO - not to set header, but set value to request DTO. How can i do this?

Just imagine that my request DTO seems like that:

```
public class RequestDTO{
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    // getters and setters for field1 and field2
}

public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    String value = request.getHeader("some_value");

    // how to add header to request DTO?
    // something like request.getRequest().setField1(value);
}
```

Comment: Unfornately, I don't think you can do it with the current your setup as I presume you are using `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`. The only thing that you can use is a simple `Filter` as shown in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38616378/471481

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not directly map into DTO class but can get all header key value in a map. For Example:

```
 @RequestMapping
public String handleRequestWithAllHeaders (@RequestHeader Map<String, String> header,
                                           Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("msg", "Trade request with all headers " + headers);
    return "my-page";
}
```

or you can find [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-mvc-request-header.html) to more options

Answer (score 0):

to set values in the request object : `something like request.getRequest().setAttribute(id,value);`